# How do I use Drools with a PHP application?

Tags: php, soap, drools

I have a PHP application my company has chosen to adopt on the one hand. We have already implemented a rules engine (Drools) for our Java application. Everything is running through a middleware platform via SOAP messaging. I know we are going to have to do a bunch of custom classes for our PHP application to handle situations that could be handled via the rules engine.

How do I integrate Drools with our PHP application? Should I just stick with SOAP messaging from the PHP app through our ESB to the rules engine and back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try not to add more moving parts to an already complicated system. I would recommend you follow your instinct and send data to be processed to the Java application via SOAP. That way you can consolidate your business logic in one area and reuse it in multiple places. That is indeed the power of distributed systems.

Answer (score 2):

You could call the Java part with Java Native Interface (JNI) from PHP. The Java part will have a public interface that receive the calls from PHP, processes the information via Drools, and then returns the anszer to PHP.
By doing this, you do not need to modify your current Java application, you just have to provide a entering point from PHP.

Start simple! Just by sending some primitive types (numbers) and retrieving them. Then, Strings, and so on, and finally passing several parameters and complex objects.

There is a project that helps to do the bridge between PHP and Java: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

The PHP documentation talks about Native calls to Java: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.java.php

Answer (score 1):

With an ESB already in place, and the fact that you are already going to use SOAP for language barriers, you should just go through the ESB.

Do not couple your application when there is already an ESB, and ESB's have BPM modules that can be endpoints.

PHP has AMQP and Stomp clients for messaging integration, or you can of course use SOAP to a service.

Ideally, your Java application, if currently coupled to the rules engine, would be using a service for this via the ESB also. Then both PHP application and Java would access the same rules engine. Rules would of course be shared and managed centrally. Worst case, you may need a Java component or  message transformer in between PHP's request and the rules engine's response.

As for an ESB being complicated, if your company already has one in place, the is complexity of the organization required it. Use the tool to keep systems decoupled and components manageable.

See these links for examples:

- http://blogs.mulesoft.org/using-mule-with-drools-and-jbpm/
- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE3USER/BPM+Module+Reference#BPMModuleReference-Usage